# Efficiently identifying whether part of string is in list/dict keys?

Tags: python, string, list, match

I have a lot (>100,000) lowercase strings in a list, where a subset might look like this:

```
str_list = ["hello i am from denmark", "that was in the united states", "nothing here"]
```

I further have a dict like this (in reality this is going to have a length of around ~1000):

```
dict_x = {"denmark" : "dk", "germany" : "ger", "norway" : "no", "united states" : "us"}
```

For all strings in the list which contain any of the dict's keys, I want to replace the **entire string** with the corresponding dict value. The expected result should thus be:

```
str_list = ["dk", "us", "nothing here"]
```

What is the most efficient way to do this given the number of strings I have and the length of the dict?

Extra info: There is never more than one dict key in a string.

Comment: do you really have a variable for each string or are they in a list or something?

Comment: They are in a list, sorry

Comment: Please show a full example of what you mean--all data and relevant code, the expected output, and the actual output. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The desired behaviour seems clear to me. The question is: "What is the most efficient way to do this"?

Comment: Since I can't answer in detail, here's the idea: you need a multiple string search algorithm. Aho–Corasick or Rabin–Karp are the more common. You'll easily find libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

```
lst = ["hello i am from denmark", "that was in the united states", "nothing here"]
dict_x = {"denmark" : "dk", "germany" : "ger", "norway" : "no", "united states" : "us"}
```

You can do:

```
res = [dict_x.get(next((k for k in dict_x if k in my_str), None), my_str) for my_str in lst]
```

which returns:

```
print(res)  # -> ['dk', 'us', 'nothing here']
```

The cool thing about this (apart from it being a python-ninjas favorite weapon aka *list-comprehension*) is the `get` with a default of `my_str` and `next` with a `StopIteration` value of `None` that triggers the above default.

Comment: Very nice, thanks. So far I find this to be the most efficient way

Comment: Should be faster (no get) : `[next((v for k,v in dict_x.items() if k in my_str), my_str) for my_str in lst]`

Comment: @jferard I do not think that iterating through the dict would be faster than `get`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I don't know the details of python's dict implementation, but usually a hashtable is an array of references on linked lists of pairs (key, value). (Every key of a list has the same hash). If you iterate through the keys, you take each cell of the array and then explore each list. Retrieving the value is a no-cost operation. In your inner list comprehension, you iterate throught the keys. Then you take the first key, *hash it, go to the cell and explore the list again to find the value.* I just iterate though the (key, value) pairs and take the first pair.

Comment: A confirmation with `dis` module would be welcome...

Comment: @Ev.Kounis My apologies: you were right. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/49586775/6914441

Comment: @jferard No worries. Nicely done!

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a good way:

```
input_strings = ["hello i am from denmark",
                 "that was in the united states",
                 "nothing here"]
dict_x = {"denmark" : "dk", "germany" : "ger", "norway" : "no", "united states" : "us"}

output_strings = []

for string in input_strings:
    for key, value in dict_x.items():
        if key in string:
            output_strings.append(value)
            break
    else:
        output_strings.append(string)
print(output_strings)
```

Comment: nice use of `else` on the `for` and a solid, basic approach. +1

Comment: Small corner case: without taking into account whitespace or word boundaries, there will be false positives from using `in`: e.g. the key ‘france’ will match ‘hello my name is francesca’

Comment: @jez: You are right. The solution for that depends on the actual input data and the constraints that it has.

Comment: You can say `if key in string.split()` but there’s a performance penalty of course.

Comment: That would be a quick fix. Necessity depends on the structure of the input data and if that case can even happen. Since the OP asked for efficiency I have not added it.

Comment: @jez If you use `split` you will lose `"united states"`..

Comment: This is actually more efficient than my answer, which uses a similar method, but the OP stated the output was the same list. If using a different output variable is not an issue, I think your answer is most efficient (given the possibility of ~1000 strings in the list).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work. Note that this will convert the string to the first encountered key fitting the criteria. If there are multiple you may want to modify the logic based on whatever fits your use case.

```
strings = [str1, str2, str3]
converted = []
for string in strings:
    updated_string = string
    for key, value in dict_x.items()
        if key in string:
            updated_string = value
            break
    converted.append(updated_string)
print(converted)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
str_list = ["hello i am from denmark", "that was in the united states", "nothing here"]

dict_x = {"denmark" : "dk", "germany" : "ger", "norway" : "no", "united states" : "us"}

for k, v in dict_x.items():
    for i in range(len(str_list)):
        if k in str_list[i]:
            str_list[i] = v

print(str_list)
```

This iterates through the key, value pairs in your dictionary and looks to see if the key is in the string. If it is, it replaces the string with the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass `dict` and use a list comprehension.

In terms of performance, I advise you try a few different methods and see what works best.

```
class dict_contains(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, value):
        key = next((k for k in self.keys() if k in value), None)
        return self.get(key)

str1 = "hello i am from denmark"
str2 = "that was in the united states"
str3 = "nothing here"

lst = [str1, str2, str3]

dict_x = dict_contains({"denmark" : "dk", "germany" : "ger", "norway" : "no", "united states" : "us"})

res = [dict_x[i] or i for i in lst]

# ['dk', 'us', "nothing here"]
```