# Is it possible to call a function from within a list comprehension without the overhead of calling the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, bytecode

In this trivial example, I want to factor out the `i < 5` condition of a list comprehension into it's own function. I also want to eat my cake and have it too, and avoid the overhead of the `CALL_FUNCTION` bytecode/creating a new frame in the python virtual machine.

**Is there any way to factor out the conditions inside of a list comprehension into a new function but somehow get a disassembled result that avoids the large overhead of `CALL_FUNCTION`?**

```
import dis
import sys
import timeit

def my_filter(n):
    return n < 5

def a():
    # list comprehension with function call
    return [i for i in range(10) if my_filter(i)]

def b():
    # list comprehension without function call
    return [i for i in range(10) if i < 5]

assert a() == b()

>>> sys.version_info[:]
(3, 6, 5, 'final', 0)

>>> timeit.timeit(a)
1.2616060493517098
>>> timeit.timeit(b)
0.685117881097812

>>> dis.dis(a)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x0000020F4890B660, file "<stdin>", line 3>)
  # ...

>>> dis.dis(b)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x0000020F48A42270, file "<stdin>", line 3>)
  # ...

# list comprehension with function call
# big overhead with that CALL_FUNCTION at address 12
>>> dis.dis(a.__code__.co_consts[1])
3         0 BUILD_LIST               0
          2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
    >>    4 FOR_ITER                16 (to 22)
          6 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
          8 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (my_filter)
         10 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
         12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
         14 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        4
         16 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
         18 LIST_APPEND              2
         20 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
    >>   22 RETURN_VALUE

# list comprehension without function call
>>> dis.dis(b.__code__.co_consts[1])
3         0 BUILD_LIST               0
          2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
    >>    4 FOR_ITER                16 (to 22)
          6 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
          8 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
         10 LOAD_CONST               0 (5)
         12 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
         14 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        4
         16 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
         18 LIST_APPEND              2
         20 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
    >>   22 RETURN_VALUE
```

I'm willing to take a hacky solution that I would never use in production, like somehow replacing the bytecode at run time.

In other words, is it possible to replace `a`'s addresses 8, 10, and 12 with `b`'s 8, 10, and 12 at runtime?

Comment: *I'm willing to take a hacky solution that I would never use in production* - is it worth considering?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest for educational purposes - sure.

Comment: Feels like your time would be better spent learning something like Cython, to be honest.

Comment: I imagine your best option is to generate the code for the listcomp at run-time and then [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) it.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're looking for a way to inline a function... there is no such thing in CPython, although attempts have been made: https://bugs.python.org/issue10399

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consolidating all of the excellent answers in the comments into one.

As georg says, this sounds like you are looking for a way to inline a function or an expression, and there is no such thing in CPython attempts have been made: https://bugs.python.org/issue10399

Therefore, along the lines of "metaprogramming", you can build the lambda's inline and eval:

```
from typing import Callable
import dis

def b():
    # list comprehension without function call
    return [i for i in range(10) if i < 5]

def gen_list_comprehension(expr: str) -> Callable:
    return eval(f"lambda: [i for i in range(10) if {expr}]")

a = gen_list_comprehension("i < 5")
dis.dis(a.__code__.co_consts[1])
print("=" * 10)
dis.dis(b.__code__.co_consts[1])
```

which when run under 3.7.6 gives:

```
 6           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                16 (to 22)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
              8 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (5)
             12 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             14 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        4
             16 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             18 LIST_APPEND              2
             20 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   22 RETURN_VALUE
==========
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                16 (to 22)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
              8 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (5)
             12 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             14 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        4
             16 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             18 LIST_APPEND              2
             20 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   22 RETURN_VALUE
```

From a security standpoint "eval" is dangerous, athough here it is less so because what you can do inside a lambda. And what can be done in an IfExp expression is even more limited, but still dangerous like call a function that does evil things.

However, if you want the same effect that is more secure, instead of working with strings you can modify AST's. I find that a lot more cumbersome though.

A hybrid approach would be the call `ast.parse()` and check the result. For example:

```
import ast
def is_cond_str(s: str) -> bool:
    try:
        mod_ast = ast.parse(s)
        expr_ast = isinstance(mod_ast.body[0])
        if not isinstance(expr_ast, ast.Expr):
            return False
        compare_ast = expr_ast.value
        if not isinstance(compare_ast, ast.Compare):
            return False
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

This is a little more secure, but there still may be evil functions in the condition so you could keep going. Again, I find this a little tedious.

Coming from the other direction of starting off with bytecode, there is my cross-version assembler; see https://pypi.org/project/xasm/